# Как писать unit тесты для DAL?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

К примеру есть классы с такими extension методами:

```
IQueryable<UserViewDto> ToViewDto(this IQueryable<UserEntity> query)
```

Или элементарный Linq запрос (в другом классе):

```
_repository.Query<UserEntity>
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Where(x=>x.Type == UserType.Oldfag)
                .ToViewDto()
                .ToList();
```

Каждый раз в тестовом методе заполнять список с `UserEntity` делать `AsQueryable()` уж очень долго.

Как вариант рассматриваю сделать какой нибудь набор данных всех сущностей с разными свойствами. Но это тоже долго и усложняет чтение тестового кода, т.к. придется находить место где сущности перечислены, искать нужную с нужными параметрами и только потом сравнивать его свойства.

Подскажите как правильно поступить? Или я иду в направлении интеграционных тестов и DAL вообще не стоит трогать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Каждый раз в тестовом методе заполнять список с UserEntity делать
>   AsQueryable() уж очень долго.

Именно так и надо делать. В результате вы получите юнит-тесты в чистом виде, без сторонней зависимости в виде БД. И это не должно быть долго, поскольку набор входных данных должен получаться небольшой, если тестовые методы у вас достаточно хорошо разбиты по соответствуют отдельным кейсам.

> Или я иду в направлении интеграционных тестов и DAL вообще не стоит
>   трогать?

Тесты всякие нужны, тесты всякие важны. И на DAL в т.ч. Просто если у вас нет в БД никакой логики, то тогда вы сможете замокать ее, и получить чистые юнит-тесты. Если же в БД есть логика, то придется делать и интеграционные тесты (тут, впрочем, можно подискутировать на тему того, стоит ли тестировать БДшный код из тестов приложения или иметь отдельные тесты для процедур).

Comment: В DAL стараюсь логику не писать, если она есть, то минимальная. Меня интересовало именно то, надо ли на каждый класс выборки заполнять список с UserEntity. (Этих классов-выборок примерно 150). Сам по себе UserEntity сам достаточно большой. И каждый раз его создавать проблема (как мне кажется).

Comment: Еще тогда один вопрос: получается надо делать разные вариации списка UserEntity? Т.е.: в продуктовом коде условие типа Where(x=>x.Type == UserType.Oldfag).Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted).Where(еще что то). И на каждое условие придется заполнять по несколько вариантов UserEntity? P.S. Я не говорил про зависимость от БД. Я говорил про то, чтобы создать набор каких то данных и работать с ними в памяти

Comment: @Prekal *"И на каждое условие придется заполнять по несколько вариантов UserEntity?"* -- да. При этом вам, скорее всего, не нужно заполнять все поля `UserEntity`. Достаточно лишь те, которые важны в контексте теста.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, тут нужно разделять тесты DAL-а, от тестов *пользователей DAL-а*.

Вот, например, как протестировать приведенный фрагмент?:

```
_repository.Query<UserEntity>
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Where(x=>x.Type == UserType.Oldfag)
                .ToViewDto()
                .ToList();
```

Для этого нужно проверить: (1) что DAL реализован корректно и (2) что связка `DAL_Client -> DAL -> Data Store` работают корректно.

Разбиваем этот процесс на две части:

**Тесты реализации DAL-а**

- Парсинг деревьев выражений
- Применение предикатов для фильтрации содержимого
- SQL-генератор
- Работу методов `Select` и других методов `IQueriable`
- Корректность работы метода `ToViewDto`

Данные тесты могут (и должны) использовать классы, отличные от `UserEntity`: для этого подойдут дата-объекты.

**Тесты связки `DAL_Client -> DAL -> DataStore`**

Теперь нужно проверить, что использование репозитория в приведенном виде приводит к корректным результатам. При этом нет никакого смысла проверить парсинг выражений и работу предикатов. Эту связку нужно уже интеграционными тестами, поскольку важно, чтобы end-to-end сценарий использования репозитория приводил к нужным результатам.

Подобные вызовы можно завернуть в фасадные классы, а можно оставить прямо в контроллерах, сервисах. Это зависит от их числа и сложности.

Сложно сказать сейчас, есть ли смысл мокать репозиторий с `UserEntity`, поскольку не ясно, будет ли при этом проверяться что-то, что еще не было покрыто в первом разделе юнит-тестами, которые работали с произвольными дата-объектами.

Я бы начал с интеграционных тестов, ведь они все равно нужны. Потом, если будет понятно, что нужны более низкоуровневые тесты, то уже бы добавлял их по мере необходимости.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того насколько изменчив список с UserEntity.

1. Если редко, или один список на все тесты - положить данные в файл/json и грузить данные в каждом тесте.
2. Если каждый тест - свой список - использовать много файлов или использовать аналог [approvaltests](http://approvaltests.com/)